# Formatting file rows using UNIX commands

Tags: unix

I have file contents as:

```
file1.txt|file2.txt|file2.txt|.............................fileN.txt
log1.txt|log2.txt|log3.txt|................logN.txt
```

I want to print it **from right to left for each row** as:
Output:

```
fileN.txt|fileN-1.txt|fileN-2.txt|.............................file1.txt
logN.txt|logN-1.txt|logN-2.txt|................log1.txt
```

Please help or let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: and also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "|" '{ for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s", $i (i==1 ? "\n" : FS) }' file
```

Testing:

Contents of `file`:

```
file1.txt|file2.txt|file3.txt|file4.txt|file5.txt|file6.txt
log1.txt|log2.txt|log3.txt|log4.txt|log5.txt
```

Results:

```
file6.txt|file5.txt|file4.txt|file3.txt|file2.txt|file1.txt
log5.txt|log4.txt|log3.txt|log2.txt|log1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write simple perl script when you read this file...
chop the line with `"|"` sperater and put it into one array and then again write this array with reverse index to file.

I hope you understand the algo

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I understand your algo. But I am unfamiliar to perl script.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer Python

```
for line in open("file.txt").read().split("\n"):
    print "|".join(line.split("|")[::-1])
```